# How to sum a vlook up and return zeros?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to add up a column of number returned using `vlookup`. When I use `Sum`, it returns a blank if the vlookup returns `#N/A`, as the cell has no value. Can I then get this to show a zero instread of `#N/A` so the above `sum` works  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional:

```
=IF(ISERROR(<cell>),0,SUM(<...>))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your VLOOKUP formula in IFERROR function, e.g.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B1:C10,2,FALSE),0)`